# Trouble locating css blocking button functionality

Tags: html, css, bigcommerce

i have a site, 4yourtype.com. On the home page there is a button "Blood Type Diet App" i'm tryin to replace it with a dropdown menu button. However whenever i add the following the drop menu does not appear but does seem to be working:

```
<div class="Cusdropbtn">
    <button onclick="cusMenu()" class="Cusdropbtn has-child">I'm here to...</button>
    <div id="myDropdown" class="Cusdropbtn-content">
        <ul>
            <!--edit links here-->
            <li><a href="/weight-loss-for-type-o/" class="selected">Weight Loss</a></li>
            <li><a href="/energy-management-for-type-o/">Gain Energy</a></li>
            <li><a href="/reduce-stress-for-type-o/">Reduce Stress</a></li>
            <li><a href="/immune-seasonal-support-for-type-o/">Immune &amp; Seasonal Support</a></li>
            <li><a href="/type-o-best-sellers/">See Best Sellers</a></li>
        </ul>
     </div>
 </div>
```

I have tried replacing and removing most of the css and just cant seem to find what is stopping it from functioning properly. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I tried replacing the code between the `<li></li>` tag where the current button resides.

Comment: Can you explain what's not working properly? It would also be beneficial to see your cusMenu function. Note that CSS will probably never "stop [something] from functioning properly." It just styles elements, so any functionality is either inherent to the HTML elements or a result of JavaScript acting on the page.

Comment: if you go to this page - http://www.4yourtype.com/jims-test-page/ you will see the button working ("i'm here to..."). The part the is not working is when i click the dropdown, the dropdown does not show up, almost like its z-index is set to a very low number. The actual functionality of the button is working. i used firebug to replace the html of the button currently in place as mentioned above. If i remove the class entirely from the <ul> as well as the <div> container the button does function.

Comment: Just cant seem to figure out which individual css property is causing the issue.

Comment: Well if it helps, it works fine for me (Chrome 53.0.2785.143 (64-bit) and Firefox 49, Kubuntu 16.04).

Comment: I just tried it in the same version of chrome, Could you show me where you placed the code Dominic? I know that if you place it outside the <ul></ul> it will work

Comment: I didn't modify anything. i just went to your test site and tried it, and it works fine (now Firefox 40.0.3 on Windows 10).

http://i.imgur.com/UDyVvKF.png

Comment: Exactly, the button functions properly except when i try to place it as a list item in the unordered list at the top menu http://polymorphisims2015.com/scripts/jim/button_issue.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I understand your problem, I've discovered the solution. You have conflicting styles in your menu: specifically your dropdown list (`.Cusdropbtn-content ul`) and generic lists in the header (`.sf-menu ul`, `.PageMenu li ul`).

You'll see that the latter styles both have the same or higher specificity and are defined later in stylesheets with higher priority than yours.

My first note is that your custom styles should be included *after* the base styles in your HEAD element to ensure that any style you overwrite have priority. Second, both `.sf-menu ul` and `.PageMenu li ul` set the position of the list to absolute, which means that it's being moved out of its container. You should have something like `postion: static !important` on `.Cusdropbtn-content ul` if you want to ensure that it is unaffected by the offending styles.